Why people should worship of god?
Here are some reasons why people worship God (or gods), depending on the religion:

Connection to Something Higher:  Many find comfort and purpose in believing in a higher power that created and guides the universe.

Source of Morality and Meaning: Religious teachings often provide a moral compass and a sense of meaning in life.

Community and Belonging:  Religion can provide a strong sense of community and belonging, with shared rituals and traditions.

Hope and Strength:  Faith can offer solace in times of hardship and provide hope for a better future or afterlife.

Love and Gratitude:  Worship can be a way to express love and gratitude for the blessings in life.

Sense of Peace and Purpose:  Many find spiritual practices like prayer and meditation to bring inner peace and a sense of purpose.


It's important to remember that these are just some reasons, and people choose to worship for a wide variety of personal reasons.

It all depends on what is the definition of the term "WORSHIP"? Does Any ritual constitute worship? If so then, people worship because they want to be parented (Guided, protected, nurtured, rewarded). There is the reason for worship.
